# nhibernate criteria, like on words

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I want to do this with a nhibernate criteria:

```
SELECT Text FROM Table WHERE Text Like 'Re% Wi%'
```

The result should be:

```
Red Wine
```

I have the search parameter as a string 'Re Wi' from the user interface.

What is the best approach? split the string and put % at the end, join the string array and end up with:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Text", 'Re% Wi%', MatchMode.Start))
```

Or can I add the individual parts (beginning of words) to some criteria expression?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your current approach.

Comment: i have to agree with vadim, the criteria api does not allow for this particular manipulation so just insert the '%' on after each token

Comment: Ok, I'll do the % on each token approach, just thought that I've missed some API stuff since I'm new to writing criteria